# Use Java to read from a REST service

Tags: c#, java, http, http-authentication

I am trying to figure out how to read from a REST source that requires authentication and having no luck. I have this working fine using C# as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(filename);
request.Accept = "application/xml";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.KeepAlive = true;

// this part is not used until after a request is refused, but we add it anyways
CredentialCache myCache = new CredentialCache();
myCache.Add(new Uri(filename), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
request.Credentials = myCache;

// this is how we put the uname/pw in the first request
string cre = String.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cre);
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
return response.GetResponseStream();
```

But for Java the following is not working:

```
URL url = new URL(dsInfo.getFilename());
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
String encodedCredential = encoder.encode( (dsInfo.getUsername() + ":" + dsInfo.getPassword()).getBytes() );
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "BASIC " + encodedCredential);

conn.connect();

InputStream responseBodyStream = conn.getInputStream();
```

The stream is returning:

```
Error downloading template

Packet: test_packet
Template: NorthwindXml

Error reading authentication header.
```

What am I getting wrong?

thanks - dave

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Have you tried using Wireshark to see what differs on the network between the two methods?

Comment: OOPS - sorry. Added the result above.

Comment: How certain are you that the server is implementing RFC 2617 properly? For example, does it know that the auth-scheme token is case insentive?

Comment: Write "Basic " instead of "BASIC " and try again.

Answer (score 2):

In your encoding of username/password:

Java uses UTF-8 encoding, and getBytes() returns the bytes corresponding to the local host encoding (who may be or not ASCII). The [javadoc of String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) gives you more detail.

Print the values of such encoded Strings both in c# and Java and check if they match.

Answer (score 1):

The answer came from Codo in a comment - Basic instead of BASIC.